# trying to write a LINQ query using contains and starts with from a List

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Using VS 2017 in C#
I have a working solution that has had the scope expanded.
Originally it only needed to return a dataset where a goodRMA_flag was set to true if line.RMANumber contained or started with two different variables.

This is the original code, that works fine:

```
string mask1 = "/078";
string mask2 = "078";

        //start with all of them, flag the good and bad
        var RMA_stops_all = (from rma in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                             join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on rma.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                             where line.RmaNumber != null
                             &&
                             (line.DatetimeCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma) &&
                             line.DatetimeCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma).AddDays(7))
                             && rma.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                             select new
                             {
                                 DatetimeCreated = line.DatetimeCreated,
                                 UniqueIdNo = rma.UniqueIdNo,
                                 RmaNumber = line.RmaNumber,
                                 RmaOriginalUniqueId = line.RmaOriginalUniqueId,
                                 ItemSequenceNo = line.ItemSequenceNo,
                                 ItemNumber = line.ItemNumber,
                                 goodRMA_flag = (line.RmaNumber.Contains(mask1) || line.RmaNumber.StartsWith(mask2)),
                                 RMA_cleanedUp = line.RmaNumber.Substring(line.RmaNumber.IndexOf("/") + 1)
                             }).ToArray();
```

Now they have expanded the requirement to where any number of masks may be needed.
I am building a list of all needed matches using this code:

```
  int startingMask = 75;
            int numberNumberNeeded = 10;
            List<string> masksContains = new List<string>();
            List<string> masksStartsWith = new List<string>();

            while (numberNumberNeeded > 0)
            {
            string newMask = (++startingMask).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                masksStartsWith.Add(newMask);
                newMask = newMask.PadLeft(4, '/');
                masksContains.Add(newMask);
                numberNumberNeeded--;
            }
```

Now that I have the list I was wanting to change the line for the goodRMA_flag to something like:

```
goodRMA_flag = (line.RmaNumber.Contains(masksContains) || line.RmaNumber.StartsWith(masksStartsWith)),
```

I am assuming I will need some sort of Lamda but I have not been able to get the syntax correct despite multiple swings at it.

EDIT:
Using --

```
    goodRMA_flag = (masksContains.Any(masks => line.RmaNumber.Contains(masks)) ||
 masksStartsWith.Any(masks => line.RmaNumber.StartsWith(masks))),
```

Gives a runtime error of:
"System.NotSupportedException: 'Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.'

**solution** -- here is the final working code for reference:

```
 //a integer that we are starting with - this needs to come from
 //a database at some point
        int startingMask = 75;
        //how far ahead to look
        int qtyNeeded= 10;
        //will hold the strings that RMA_Number needs to contain
        List<string> masksContains = new List<string>();
        //will hold the strings that RMA_Number needs to start with
        List<string> masksStartsWith = new List<string>();

        //Build the two lists
        while (qtyNeeded> 0)
        {
        string newMask = (++startingMask).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
            masksStartsWith.Add(newMask);
            newMask = newMask.PadLeft(4, '/');
            masksContains.Add(newMask);
            qtyNeeded--;
        }

        //start with all of them, flag them all as bad -- will then step through and fix
        var RMA_stops_all = (from rma in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                             join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on rma.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                             where line.RmaNumber != null
                             &&
                             (line.DatetimeCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma) &&
                             line.DatetimeCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(dateToCheck_rma).AddDays(7))
                             && rma.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                             select new RMA_Items
                             {
                                 DatetimeCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(line.DatetimeCreated),
                                 UniqueIdNo = rma.UniqueIdNo,
                                 RmaNumber = line.RmaNumber,
                                 RmaOriginalUniqueId = Convert.ToDecimal(line.RmaOriginalUniqueId),
                                 ItemSequenceNo = Convert.ToDecimal(line.ItemSequenceNo),
                                 ItemNumber = line.ItemNumber,
                                 goodRMA_flag = false,
                                 RMA_cleanedUp = line.RmaNumber.Substring(line.RmaNumber.IndexOf("/") + 1)
                             }).ToArray();

        //convert it to a new list that we can step through
        var rmaStopsAllList = RMA_stops_all.ToList();

        //go through the new list, set the goodRMA_flag for the items that meet our criteria
        rmaStopsAllList.ForEach(x => x.goodRMA_flag =
            (masksContains.Any(masks => x.RmaNumber.Contains(masks))
             || masksStartsWith.Any(masks => x.RmaNumber.StartsWith(masks)))&&
             x.RMA_cleanedUp.Length==10);

        //flip it back into our original array
        RMA_stops_all = rmaStopsAllList.ToArray();

        //pull out the good ones
        var RMA_Stops_GoodRMA = (from R in RMA_stops_all
                    where R.goodRMA_flag == true
                    select R).ToArray();

        //pull out the bad ones
        var RMA_Stops_BadRMA = (from B in RMA_stops_all
                             where B.goodRMA_flag == false
                             select B).ToArray();
```

Along with a new class:

```
class RMA_Items
{
    public DateTime DatetimeCreated { get; set; }
    public decimal UniqueIdNo { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemSequenceNo { get; set; }
    public string RmaNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal RmaOriginalUniqueId { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public bool goodRMA_flag { get; set; }
    public string RMA_cleanedUp { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `line.RmaNumber.Where(num => num.Contanins(masksContains)) ` is that what you mean?

Comment: Contains is more that enough, I think. No need for StartWith.
Contains in a string is basically indexof >= 0
On new changes, you would have to do something like @Gusman said, plus .Count() > 0 or similar.

Comment: contains is not more than enough.  That would mean that this "11555466307877646" would pass which would be wrong.  It either has to have the mask of /0xx embedded somewhere in it OR start with 0xx -- with xx being a range of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `line.RmaNumber` should contain any of the masks available in `masksContains`. Or, alternatively `line.RmaNumber` should start with one of the masks defined in `masksStartsWith`. If any of these conditions is met, then `goodRMA_flag` will be set to `true`. Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
goodRMA_flag = (masksContains.Any(masks => line.RmaNumber.Contains(masks))
    || masksStartsWith.Any(masks => line.RmaNumber.StartsWith(masks)))
```

**EDIT:** However since LINQ to SQL doesn't allow this because `line.RmaNumber` is coming from SQL directly, we can instead update the flag in the next step since `RmaNumber` is available in the object.

```
var rmaStopsAllList = RMA_stops_all.ToList();
rmaStopsAllList.Foreach(x => x.goodRMA_flag = 
    (masksContains.Any(masks => x.RmaNumber.Contains(masks))
     || masksStartsWith.Any(masks => x.RmaNumber.StartsWith(masks))));
RMA_stops_all = rmaStopsAllList.ToArray();
```

**EDIT 2:** Also need to declare an actual class instead of using anonymous type so that it can be assigned to later (as shown above). `goodRMA_flag` should be a property in the class and can be set to any value in the previous step.

```
select new SomeClass    
{
    // Other initialization here
    goodRMA_flag = false,
}).ToArray();
```

instead of

```
select new
{
    // Other initialization here
    goodRMA_flag = false,
}).ToArray();
```

and most importantly, be sure add a new class definition for this purpose with the correct data types:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string DateTime DatetimeCreated {get; set;}
    public string UniqueIdNo {get; set;}
    public string RmaNumber {get; set;}
    public int RmaOriginalUniqueId {get; set;}
    public string ItemSequenceNo {get; set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get; set;}
    public bool goodRMA_flag {get; set;}
    public string RMA_cleanedUp {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is there any need for StartWith?

Comment: @JuanCarlos Yes, I believe the OP wants the flag to be set when either of the masks are found

Comment: RmaNumber is string, so Contains checks for a substring inside that one. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx
I think there is no need for startwith

Comment: I need it to find records that either start with "078' OR contain "/078" with the number portion being a range that will change over time.  We have drivers that are either scanning a barcode (which will have a value like "113342/078664554" with the needed mask in the middle OR they will be manually typing it in which will then be "078664554".  But they sometimes scan the wrong barcode such as the zip code bar code so there will be some records that will have values like "62220" or even "AZ77756665" -- that is why I am using a masks to try and clean up the dataset as much as possible.

Comment: @JuanCarlos There are 2 different lists being used for `StartsWith` and `Contains`. I think you are assuming that the same item is being compared.

Comment: @degant -- I was still editing the OP.  No, it does compile but has a runtime error of "System.NotSupportedException: 'Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.'

Comment: since it looks like contains is OK but StartsWith is the problem can we somehow use contains but limit it to checking just the first 3 characters?

Comment: well " masksStartsWith.Any(masks => line.RmaNumber.ToString().Substring(0,3).Contains(masks)" gives the same error...

Comment: @JoeRuder Your question say: "contained or started with two different variables."  Now it's the same but X ammount of variables. So if it's contained or started. Then you don't need started. But if it's only checking 3 chararters, then just check if len > 3 and substring it and compare it with mask.

Comment: @JoeRuder Take a look at the update. Since you are saving `RmaNumber` in the new array. How about you update the `goodRMA_flag` in the next step so that we will be able to fully leverage LINQ.

Comment: sorry Juan for the confussion.  It needs to *either* contain one variable (that is in a list) OR start with a different one -- that is in a different list.  So...list one will have 10 items that it can contain and list two will have 10 *different* items that it needs to start with.

Comment: @JoeRuder check my new answer. Or accept this one, because it's basically the same. Problem is that you don't have that list in SQL server. You need to get results to local, toArray will work. and then you can select those results again and create objects with desire properties.

Comment: I think we are close...but it is thinking that something is read only : Error CS0200 Property or indexer '<anonymous type: DateTime? DatetimeCreated, decimal UniqueIdNo, string RmaNumber, decimal? RmaOriginalUniqueId, decimal ItemSequenceNo, string ItemNumber, bool goodRMA_flag, string RMA_cleanedUp>.goodRMA_flag' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot anonymous types are immutable. To fix this, in the previous step when you are creating the anonymous type, can you instead define and create an actual class object with the same properties. That'll fix this issue. Instead of `select new {` use `select new SomeNewClass {`

Comment: I think this is working, I am doing some testing to make sure and I will update soon....thanks for much for the assist.

Comment: @JoeRuder used a new class or a second select new {}?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
 The main problem is that this is LinqToSql and he is referencing a local sequence in the select statement. 
You would have to get the results and create a new object with the local results.

Hope I'm not getting your question wrong.

```
var db = new string[]{ "1", "2", "41", "C", "ka"};
var masks = new string[] { "a", "1" };
var query = from n in db
    select new
    {
       n = n,
       t = masks.Where(x=> n.Contains(x)).Count() > 0, //works
       t2 = masks.Any(x=> n.Contains(x)) //best approach
    };
```

As you can see, just need to check for Contains.

1, 41 and ka, gets true.

Comment: Thanks for the swing Juan, but that does not meet the original need.

Comment: @JoeRuder I will update this answer, because I think we all got it wrong.

Comment: Looking at this it only does the contains and not the starts with.  for "078" we need 07866455 to pass but 05576078 to fail.

Comment: Thats just a matter of chaning the conditions. Just need to move the result out of sql.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to create a method that returns a boolean. It will accept a list of masks. If a mask does not match, you return false.

When you have this method created, you could pass it to the lambda.